# Integrate Stripe payments with create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I want to properly integrate stripe charges with my create method in controller.

```
   def create
    @individual_training = IndividualTraining.new(individual_training_params)
    Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        amount: (@individual_training.training_cost.cost * 100).floor,
        currency: 'pln',
        card: token
      )
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:danger] = e.message
      render :new
    end

    if @individual_training.save
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Pomyślnie dodano.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

The issue is with properly validation whole form. Beside Stripe fields I have also fields designed for @individual_training. When Stripe doesn't have any error, but @individual_training has, stripe registered payment. I want record stripe charges when @individual_training.save is true and conversely.

If data are correct in first part(stripe fields) and second part of the form(@individual_training fields), then a payment should be registered and @individual_training.save.

I hope that clearly explain the problem.

Comment: Do you need something like Active Record valid? [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F)

Comment: @PavelBulanov do you mean, using this: if charge.valid? && individual_training.save

Comment: @PavelBulanov When I use charge.valid? there is error: undefined method for for #<Stripe::Charge:0x007fe8ea4751c8>>.

Comment: Valid? Is for your active record object, I.e. individual_training. You can run it to verify if there are any validation errors, but not saving object to DB. Do it before running Stripe command

Comment: @PavelBulanov, ok but there is a problem when individual_training is valid, but Stripe not. Object save to database, while process payment is invalid.

Comment: See answer with explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you wrote in comments, following should do the thing for you

```
 def create
    @individual_training = IndividualTraining.new(individual_training_params)
    ..
    if @individual_training.valid? # run validation, ensure it's ok, but not yet save
      begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(..) # if there is exception rescue block is called
        ...
        # unless you modified individual_training following save will be positive
        if !charge.errors? && @individual_training.save # save should be true as you checked valid? before
          redirect_to :back, notice: 'error'
        else
          render :new # this is if charge has errors
        end          
      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        flash[:danger] = e.message
        render :new
      end     
    else # this happens if individual_training  is not valid
      render :new
    end
  end
```

The code for `charge.errors?` should be changed to actual check of Stripe operation result.

Comment: now it's look that it works properly, but now I have problem with this error: Missing template backend/individual_trainings/create.

Comment: In what case it happens? Also, I added else statement in the code (see above), which would render new template in case ActiveRecord validation fails

Comment: Ok now it's ok with missing template error, but still is wrong when individual_training is valid, but stripe has some errors, because individual_training save to database but payment not.

Comment: Why individual_training is saved to DB? What kind of errors stripe has? If it's an exception - it should be caught by your rescue block and bypass save method. If it's something else (error but not an exception), you should have corresponding checks after Charge.create call.